# Data Analysis - 7 point Likert scale measuring behaviour

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, scales

I have recently conducted a study for my dissertation looking at behaviour change prior to starting a club and the child's current behaviour.

The questionnaire was structured of 8 questions about different aspects of behaviour with questions on 4 positive behaviours and 4 negative behaviours. Participants responded on a 7 point Likert scale - 1= Never 2 3 4= Sometimes 5 6 7=Always. I had 19 respondents 7 boys and 12 girls.

Hypotheses - Current occurrence of positive behaviours will be more frequent compared to their behaviours prior starting the club.

Current negative behaviours will occur less frequently than their behaviours prior to starting the club.

which tests can be used to work out the statistical significance of my results?
What would be the best way to present the data in terms of statistics?

Comment: You cannot hope to get help without explaining what research hypotheses you want to test (there's a very large number of possible tests you *might* conduct). Your post should include a specific question or questions you want answered. ("I have no idea" isn't a question ... and suggests a lack of [search and research](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)). Please edit to clarify

Comment: Apologises, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the descriptive statistics like frequency tables etc. Also mention  your research hypothesis and the variable classification like ( Independent and dependent variables), then further you can proceed with the other parts of the analysis.

Comment: While the answer is not wrong, it can be improved. Can you a bit little more specific?